# Unable to access global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

As per me, every variable declared in javascript above functions treat as global. But in my case, i unable to access that variable show `undefined`. Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc8achqn/)

**code:**

```
__getUserByRmId('sun1')
var firstCallFlag = 1;
function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
    console.log(firstCallFlag); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the variable is defined after the function is called.

You can do this. It will work.

```
var firstCallFlag = 1;
__getUserByRmId('sun1')

function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
    console.log(firstCallFlag); 
}
```

By the way, **hoisting** is JavaScript's default behavior of **moving all declarations to the top of the current scope**. So, something like this should work.

```
 firstCallFlag =1 ;
__getUserByRmId('sun1')

function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
    console.log(firstCallFlag); 
}
var firstCallFlag;
```

However, **JavaScript Initializations are Not Hoisted**. Thus, the code like below will consider the variable firstCallFlag undefined.

```
__getUserByRmId('sun1')

function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
    console.log(firstCallFlag); 
}
var firstCallFlag = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a term [**function and variable hoisting**](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting). When you create a `function` like that and a variable with `var`, they moved to the top of of all. But the `functions` are hoisted **first** before `variables`. So when you call the `function`, it sees the `function` , but doesn't see the `variable`.

Engine parses your code to this and executes line by line. So it doesn't see the `variable`.

```
function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
    console.log(firstCallFlag); 
}

__getUserByRmId('sun1')

var firstCallFlag = 1;
```

You need to call your function after the variable declaration

```js
var firstCallFlag = 1;

__getUserByRmId('sun1');

function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
    console.log(firstCallFlag); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the function after declaring the variable. Function will hoist first and then the variables.

```js
var firstCallFlag = 1;
function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
    console.log(firstCallFlag); 
}
__getUserByRmId('sun1');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var firstCallFlag = 1;
function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
    console.log(firstCallFlag); 
}
__getUserByRmId('sun1');
```

Its beacuse you have to define the variable "firstCallFlag " first and then call the function `__getUserByRmId('sun1');`....variable hoisting in javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to work with the same pattern of approach without declaring the variable on top of function call, then you should have a timeout call like this:

```
_getUserByRmId('sun1');

var firstCallFlag = 1;

function __getUserByRmId(rmId) {
   setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(firstCallFlag); 
   },1);        
}
```